# chamando Enum pelo value

Tags: c#, enums

Criei uma enum:

```
 public enum EnumTipoBoleto
    {
        VazioErro=0,
        ConfigInicial = 1,
        Mensalidade = 2,
        Outros =3,
        DifMensal =4
    }
```

Agora em alguns lugares eu tenho o número e quero converter para enum

```
var variavel = 2;
var valorEnum = EnumTipoBoleto[variavel]; //Como faço?
```

> ```
> 'EnumTipoBoleto' is a type, which is not valid in the given context
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta fazer um cast

Por exemplo:

```
var variavel = 2;
var valorEnum = (EnumTipoBoleto)variavel;
```

Comment: uhahuahua era isso mesmo..aff que vacilo meu..rs